# Sub routes for shopping experine pages

Tags: shopware6

is there a way to add subpages and custom controller actions to Shopping Experience Pages?

For example, we create a Plugin and a Custom Element which was added to the Layout Designer to a Page.

The page is now accessible at `/mypage`

How about adding a sub route and controller to this so that the user can configure the element as any other.

Is it possible or do we need to got the complete Custom Page route described [here](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-custom-page).

[EDIT]
I like to have sub-routes fora shopping-experice page,
where I added my custom block.

For example let's take a gallery block with details view.

`http://shopware.test/gallery`
should show a list of all images.

`http://shopware.test/gallery/flower1`
should show just one image.

Is something like this in scope of a custom cms-block?

I hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, can you add details?

Comment: I added more info

Answer (score 0):

What is usually the way to accomplish this, is to create two layouts, one for your gallery (master page, /gallery) and one for the details (/photo).
You would need to create also two CMS elements - one for the master and one for the details.

But for the detail page you would create a normal route with a parameter, assign the custom layout in the settings and render the page manually.

So you are still able to use a custom shopping-experience layout but the routing would be hard-coded.

To additionally accomplish the URLs you want, you need to get those URLs into the `seo_url` table by [adding custom SEO URLs (Documentation)](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/content/seo/add-custom-seo-url).

You basically need:

```
path_info: /photo/f413c1fe85e4439bba96c75e1ab9e0af
seo_path_info: /gallery/flower1/
```

You would

- add a new seo template via migration (into `seo_url_template`)
- register and implement an indexer for your URLs

If you have more than one gallery (/gallery_flowers, /gallery_animals) you might need to lookup the parent page in the indexer from the CMS pages which contain your master CMS element.